# Culture Name: en-US-EN is not a supported culture Ecplise

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Hi all I have a code in java and runs great in net beans, but when I wanna run in eclipse this Exception appears

```
Exception in thread "main" class com.aspose.ocr.internal.g: Culture Name: en-US-EN is not a supported culture

com.aspose.ocr.internal.aP.b(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.ocr.internal.aP.<init>(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.ocr.internal.aP.a(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.ocr.internal.dj.b(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.ocr.internal.aP.c(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.ocr.internal.cG.c(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.ocr.z.<init>(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.ocr.ImageStream.fromFile(Unknown Source)
I.main(I.java:33)
    at com.aspose.ocr.internal.aP.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.ocr.internal.aP.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.ocr.internal.aP.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.ocr.internal.dj.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.ocr.internal.aP.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.ocr.internal.cG.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.ocr.z.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.ocr.ImageStream.fromFile(Unknown Source)
    at I.main(I.java:33)
```

This is mi code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import com.aspose.ocr.ILanguage;
import com.aspose.ocr.ImageStream;
import com.aspose.ocr.Language;
import com.aspose.ocr.OcrEngine;

public class I {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set the paths
        String imagePath = "samples/Sample.bmp";
        String resourcesFolderPath = "../resources/resource.zip";

        // Create an instance of OcrEngine
        OcrEngine ocr = new OcrEngine();
        // Set Resources for OcrEngine
        try {
            ocr.setResource(new FileInputStream(resourcesFolderPath));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Set NeedRotationCorrection property to false
        // ocr.getConfig().setNeedRotationCorrection(false);

        // Set image file
        ocr.setImage(ImageStream.fromFile(imagePath));

        // Add language
        ILanguage language = Language.load("spanish");
        ocr.getLanguages().addLanguage(language);

        // Perform OCR and get extracted text
        try {
            if (ocr.process()) {
                System.out.println("\ranswer -> " + ocr.getText());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

My version of ecplise is Luna Release (4.4.0) and net beans 8

Thanks in advance for your time and answers

Comment: `ocr.setResource(I.class.getResourceAsStream(("/resource.zip"))` with the file placed as resource, not File.

Comment: No man I have the same error, the mistery is that the code works in netbeans but in eclipse doesn´t

Answer (score 0):

Aspose has bugs where it throws exceptions for "cultures" (called "locales" by normal people) which aren't on its hard-coded list of supported ones.

Somehow, I guess your locale string is "en-US-EN" when running under Eclipse, but not when running under NetBeans.

You could maybe try passing user.language, user.country, user.variant system properties on the command-line to override whatever Eclipse is setting when it runs the app itself.

Disclaimer, though: I don't use Eclipse myself.